# How to display record from a json object one at a time in mvc view?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, traversal

My scenario is, I'm returning a list of value as json from controller to view, then want to show just the first record on my form & after pressing the down arrow key, want to show the second & so on.

Is it possible to traverse the total json list one by one at client side or I have to return single record every time from the server with key press event via ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it you have bunch of options, one possibility might be to return your results, generate html elements in your view and hide all but the first one (with CSS). Something like (just to give you an idea):

```
@model List<string>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="@((i == 0) ? "name-highlighted" : "name")">@Model[i]</div>
}
```

And in your css something like:

```
.name {
    display: none;
}

.name-highlighted {
    /* You get the idea */
}
```

Having said that, if don't want to load all the items, you can fetch the first one only (while keeping a count) and fetch every subsequent with an ajax call.

Comment: on a performance note what would be better? To make an ajax request every time or to iterate through the list at client side? The list can be huge since I'm developing a business erp solution.

Comment: @Jain Loading a large result set that is not necessary required is a waste IMHO, so yes going the AJAX way and fetching the results 1 at a time is the right way - you might even do some caching server side and get even better performance. I would personally go for an approach where I'd fetch 10 (or an acceptable amount) results, then display them, load 10 more through AJAX ... etc.